# How to hide particular item in RecyclerView and deleting its space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to hide the current user in RequestsFragment in recyclerview. I tried to setVisibility feature. The current user's informantions are not seen to him. But there is a space still in recyclerview. How can i also delete space between other items. I mean if I have sent a request to other users I dont want to see myself at requests fragment.

```
public class RequestsFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView_friendRequestsList;
private View mainView;

private DatabaseReference friendRequestsDatabaseReference;
private DatabaseReference usersDatabaseReference;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private String current_user_id;


public RequestsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_requests, container, false);

    recyclerView_friendRequestsList = mainView.findViewById(R.id.friendRequests_list);

    recyclerView_friendRequestsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView_friendRequestsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    current_user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    friendRequestsDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend Requests");
    friendRequestsDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);
    usersDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    usersDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);

    return mainView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendRequests, RequestsFragment.FriendRequestsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendRequests, FriendRequestsViewHolder>(

            FriendRequests.class,
            R.layout.users_single_layout,
            RequestsFragment.FriendRequestsViewHolder.class,
            friendRequestsDatabaseReference

    ) {



        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendRequestsViewHolder viewHolder, FriendRequests model, final int position) {


            final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

            friendRequestsDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){


                        usersDatabaseReference.child(user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if (!user_id.equals(current_user_id)) {

                                    final String user_displayName = dataSnapshot.child("display_name").getValue().toString();
                                    final String user_thumbImage = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) {

                                        String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
                                        viewHolder.setUserOnline(userOnline);

                                    }

                                    viewHolder.setName(user_displayName);
                                    viewHolder.setImage(user_thumbImage);

                                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                            profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                                            startActivity(profileIntent);

                                        }
                                    });

                                } else {

                                    viewHolder.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                        friendRequestsDatabaseReference.child(current_user_id).child(user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("request_type")) {
                                    String request_type = dataSnapshot.child("request_type").getValue().toString();
                                    viewHolder.setRequest_type(request_type);

                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }

    };

    recyclerView_friendRequestsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}


public static class FriendRequestsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;


    public FriendRequestsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        TextView userNameView = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_displayName);
        userNameView.setText(name);

    }

    public void setRequest_type(String request_type) {

        TextView userStatusView = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
        userStatusView.setText(request_type);

    }

    public void setImage(final String thumb_image) {

        CircleImageView userImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);

        Picasso.get().load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.mipmap.default_avatar).into(userImageView);


    }

    public void setUserOnline(String online_status) {

        ImageView userOnlineView = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_online);
        if (online_status.equals("true")) {

            userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {

            userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }


    }

}
```

}

Comment: You have to remove the item from your dataset and call  `notifyItemRemoved(int position)` on your adapter.

Comment: I think `recyclerView_friendRequestsList.setHasFixedSize(true);` this could be the problem. Try commenting it